# Como definir a categoria de um app no android

Tags: java, android

Como eu defino a categoria do meu app Ex. mídia, ferramentas, social...
Seria no manifest.xml ou na playStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exato, nas configurações de loja ou **App Listing** (dependendo do locale) do aplicativo na Google Play você consegue definir a categoria, assim como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: boa... valeu denovo wakim!